# News Webpart Question - Can I filter based on a (Page Properties) column created in another site?

Tags: site, modern-pages, sitepages

I would like to use the news webpart to display news content in another site.
My issues is I don't get to see my columns that i created for filtering on the source site(It doesn't show the page properties from the source page library.
The only possible option i see listed in the dropdown that could be use is Managed Property.

Are there any workarounds for this. I

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't think you can use managed property created in one site collection inside another site collection new web part filter.

Comment: Thanks for your response.But do you have any suggestions orany idea to solve  this scenario?

Comment: Hi Ganesh, I configured using the Managed Property and it actually worked